# Foxit Phantom Trimming an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foxit

I am using a button to be able to take 3 fields and put them in another 3 field. Javascript in foxit phantom PDF editor.

```
int[] bData;
int[] cData;
for (int G = 1; G <= 3; G++){
    bData[G] = this.getField("F" + G).value;
}
int N = 1;
for (int G = 1; G <= bData.length; G++){
    if (bData[G] != null){
        cData[n] = bData[G];
        N ++;
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= cData.length; i++){
    this.getField("X" + i).value = cData[i];
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think my error was using int instead of var... its working now :) thanks for your reply.